# upgrade to pip-22.1.2 version in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am using a linux Ubuntu server.  Can I install the new pip-22.1.2 version in a python 2.7 environment?

I can only get the older version with `pip3 --version`.

Should I use virtualenv?

(the outcome is just for learning purpose)